# Convert PEM formatted public key to DER

Tags: openssl

I have a public key which is ASN.1 DER formatted shown below :

```
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 181 cons: SEQUENCE          
    3:d=1  hl=3 l= 144 cons: SEQUENCE          
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :
    8:d=2  hl=3 l= 139 prim: OCTETSTRING      [HEXDUMP]: <Some Data>
  150:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING     [HEX DUMP]:<some data>
```

I have some public key in PEM format. How can change that to the above listed key format?

Answer (score 19):

A PEM file is simply a DER file that's been Base64 encoded. To convert from one to the other you can use `openssl` with the `-inform` and `-outform` arguments.  Each one takes one of `PEM`, `DER` or `NET` (a dated Netscape format, which you can ignore).

You can change a key from one format to the other with the `openssl rsa` command (assuming it's an RSA key, of course):

```
$ openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in <filename of key in PEM format> -outform DER -out <filename of key in DER format>
writing RSA key
```

You can then view the ASN.1 encoding of that file with:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in <filename of DER file>
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE          
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim: BIT STRING
```

Of course, this is of no use to you if your key is not an RSA key, but as your question doesn't stipulate what type of key it is, I've guessed :-)

Comment: That first sentence was the gold nugget I was looking for.  Helped me with a Java programming issue.  Thank you very much.